# accessing Ruby variable(from model or controller) in SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, sass

Is there a way to access Ruby variables in SASS or do I have to make a custom function for it?

What I'm trying to do is to generate a stylesheet for each user so in the controller, I do something like:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.css{render :partial => "styles"}
  end
end
```

then in the view name _styles.haml I do this:

```
:sass
  #header
    :background url(user.banner.url)
```

is this possible at all?

*Apparently it isn't: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-ruby-code

Is there a way other than this 'dirty' code fix we did(we converted _styles partial to rhtml then)

```
#header {
  background: #efefef url(<%= @company.settings.banner.url %>);
}
```

is there a way for this in haml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a custom SassScript function ([example](http://github.com/rkh/haml-more/blob/master/lib/sass/more.rb)) that inserts the value.

Comment: how would we call the function if the argument is also a variable?

Comment: Hmm im gonna study this code and see if it works :) Thanks for the help!